# An inequality of a multivariate function: $f(x_1,...,x_n) \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n f(x_i,x_i,...,x_i) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let us assume we have a non linear function $f : \Bbb R^{n+} \to \Bbb R ^+$, and let $x = \{x_1, x_2 , ..., x_n\}$, $x_i \in \Bbb{R}^+$, further define $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n x_i$. 
My question concerns the following inequality:
$$ f(x_1,...,x_n) \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n f(x_i,x_i,...,x_i)  ~~~~~~~~(1)$$
While this could be irrelevant, but I know that the function :$$f(x_1,...,x_n) \geq f(\bar{x} ,\bar{x} ,...,\bar{x} ) ~~~~~~~~(2)$$ 
we further know
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n f(x_i,x_i,...,x_i) \geq f(\bar{x} ,\bar{x} ,...,\bar{x} ) ~~~~~~~~(3)$$
My question is there a name for (1) (or have you seen it before?), is there any (non trivial) condition that $f$ needs to satisfy to imply (1) ?
Thanks,